How to use python unittest to build global fixture?
My unit tests are written using the unittest framework. I want to refactor some repetitive setup tasks, such as creating the database and user, into a global fixture that is initialized once but can be accessed by all inherited TestCase classes.
The following are methods I've tried:

Using Pytest Decorators with Unittest: I attempted to apply pytest decorators within the unittest framework.
Creating an Inherited TestSuite Class: I set up a base TestSuite class with setUp and tearDown methods and then included all inherited TestCase classes within this suite.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
